# How to loop through tag element and getting a respective content on a display by OnClick function?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, calculator

```js
var key="";

//get key values
var x = document.getElementById("calculator");
var y = x.getElementsByTagName("span");

function calc()
{
    for(var i = 0; i <= y.length; i++)
    {
        key+=y[i].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=key;

    }
};
```

I am trying to:

- loop trough the content of all the span tags in my code (which
  contain the key values of the calculator)
  using"document.getElementsByTagName"
- when you click on a respective key of the calculator (ex.click on key
  "8"),obtain the content of only that key you are clicking
- when you get the content of that key you are clicking, add it to the
  variable key="" (ex. key+="8")
- display the result in the span called "display" which is the black
  screen of the calculator. (display on the black screen the
  number:"8")

This program basically should just get the content of the key you are clicking on the calculator and display it on the screen.

The [code](http://jsfiddle.net/8gkc2oxe/11/) I have at the moment is only looping through the span tags, getting their content but it fails since it prints all the spans content in the calculator display at the same time no matter which key you click on. 
Is there a way to fix it? I know there are other options like eventlistener or setting a function for each key, but i would like to know if this code has some logic and could be completed to perform the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your events into JS, and then run the calc function for the clicked element:

```js
var key = "";
var x = document.getElementById("calculator");
var y = x.getElementsByTagName("span");
var display = document.getElementById("display");
for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    addEvent(y[i], "click", calc);
}

function calc() {
    key += this.innerHTML;
    display.innerHTML = key;
}

function addEvent(elt, type, callback) {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        elt.addEventListener(type, callback, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        elt.attachEvent("on" + type, callback);
    }
}
```

```css
#calculator {
    width:200px;
    height:380px;
}
div span {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    float:left;
    line-height:50px;
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
    font-family:"Neue Helvetica", sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    text-align: center;
}
#display {
    width:200px;
    height:80px;
    text-align:right;
    line-height:100px;
    font-size:25px;
    overflow:hidden;
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
}
#zero {
    width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator"> <span id="display">0</span>
 <span>AC</span>
 <span>+/-</span>
 <span>%</span>
 <span>÷</span>
 <span>7</span>
 <span>8</span>
 <span>9</span>
 <span>x</span>
 <span>4</span>
 <span>5</span>
 <span>6</span>
 <span>-</span>
 <span>1</span>
 <span>2</span>
 <span>3</span>
 <span>+</span>
 <span id="zero">0</span>
 <span>.</span>
 <span>=</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. Is it practical to loop through the span content or would it be a better code getting the content by assigning an id to each key?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution.

Slightly different approach. Same result.

```js
var getKeyValue = [];
var totalKey = "";
var keys = document.getElementById("calculator").getElementsByTagName("span");

function calc(i) {
  totalKey += keys[i].innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = totalKey;
}

function getKeyValueFunction(i) {
  return function() {
    keys[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      calc(i);
    }, false);
  };
}

function initiateGetKeyValues() {
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    getKeyValue[i] = getKeyValueFunction(i);
    getKeyValue[i]();
  }
}

window.onload = initiateGetKeyValues();
```

```css
#calculator {
  width: 200px;
  height: 380px;
}
div span {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  font-family: "Neue Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
#display {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
#zero {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
  <span id="display">0</span>
  <span>AC</span>
  <span>+/-</span>
  <span>%</span>
  <span>÷</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
  <span>9</span>
  <span>x</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>-</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>+</span>
  <span id="zero">0</span>
  <span>.</span>
  <span>=</span>
</div>
```